# Issue while installing therubyracer-heroku

Tags: ruby, rubygems, therubyracer, libv8

#### Issue

I am unable to run `middleman` server, because dependency `therubyracer-heroku` is not getting installed!

#### What I have tried?

I tried installing `middleman` via the below command:

```
gem install middleman
```

And it succeeded. When I started the middleman server using the default configuration:

```
$ middleman server -p 3456 -e development
```

I got these errors:

```
$ middleman server -p 3456 -e development
Could not find libv8-3.11.8.13 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
$ bundle install
src/bootstrapper.cc: In static member function 'static bool v8::internal::Genesis::CompileScriptCached(v8::internal::Vector<const char>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::SourceCodeCache*, v8::Extension*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Context>, bool)':
src/bootstrapper.cc:1002:18: error: variable 'result' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
src/bootstrapper.cc: In member function 'bool v8::internal::Genesis::InstallNatives()':
src/bootstrapper.cc:1227:24: error: variable 'name' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [obj/release/bootstrapper.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
make: *** [build/v8/libv8.a] Error 2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/praveen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:9:in `<main>': Error compiling V8 (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /home/praveen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/praveen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/ext/v8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer-heroku (0.8.1.pre3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3'` succeeds before bundling.
$
```

I tried uninstalling `libv8` and reinstalling. None worked. Okay, those I tried were:

```
gem uninstall libv8
gem install therubyracer-heroku
gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3'
gem install therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3 # psst: I know this is crazy.
gem install therubyracer # succeeded, but this is not what I need.
gem install bundler
gem install bundle
bundle install # crazy things I tried but no luck!
```

Output of `gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3'`

```
src/bootstrapper.cc:1002:18: error: variable 'result' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
src/bootstrapper.cc: In member function 'bool v8::internal::Genesis::InstallNatives()':
src/bootstrapper.cc:1227:24: error: variable 'name' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [obj/release/bootstrapper.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
make: *** [build/v8/libv8.a] Error 2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/praveen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:9:in `<main>': Error compiling V8 (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /home/praveen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/praveen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

`Gemfile` contents for your info!

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "thin"
gem "rack-contrib"

gem "middleman"
gem "middleman-livereload", :git => "https://github.com/middleman/middleman-livereload.git"
gem "middleman-smusher", :git  => "https://github.com/middleman/middleman-smusher.git"
gem "middleman-favicon-maker", :git => "https://github.com/follmann/middleman-favicon-maker.git"


gem "slim"
gem "compass-rgbapng"
gem "sassy-buttons"

group :development do
  gem 'heroku'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
  gem 'oj'
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
  gem 'oj'
end
```

So, any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: did u try `$gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3'` on commandline?

Comment: @uDaY Yup... Same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the current version of therubyracer (0.11.4 as of this writing), and *not* therubyracer-heroku. It is no longer needed since the main gem is compatible with heroku and no longer maintained.

The ordinary gem is now compatible with heroku so just

```
gem "therubyracer"
```

in your `Gemfile` should do the trick